# One to many relationship turned into one to one relationship

Tags: ms-access, entity-relationship

I made a copy of my Access file. On that copy I have one table having a one-to-many relationship with all the other tables. On the original Access file, I decided to redo one of the tables. I deleted all records from the other tables to start anew. I am able to redo all one-to-many relationship except one that is now recognized as a one-to-one. Why is that happening?

Comment: Probably have them linked on Primary Key fields. A Primary Key field should link to a Foreign Key field.

Comment: I resolved it. The foreign key was a unique index. Changed it to 'duplicate OK'.